# Is Regular language always infinite

Tags: regular-language, dfa

I'm kind of confused by the concept of regular language.
Since all regular language can be accepted by a dfa and dfa always has loops in it. So it seems like the dfa can accpet infinite number of strings. Does it mean all regular language is infinite? What about empty set. Is it a regular language?

Comment: Whether or not the DFA has accepted the string depends on whether you've ended up at an accept state or not.  It's fairly easy to draw up a trivial DFA that accepts precisely one string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [definition of regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Formal_definition) includes the empty set.  It also includes the singleton language `{a}`, so no, not all regular languages are infinite.

Answer (score 0):

No, not all DFAs have loops in them. A regular language is one which can be accepted by a regular expression (using the mathematical, rather than pcre definition), and for example 'a' is a regular expression which matches only the exact string 'a'. So { a } is a regular language. :)

A DFA for this language is:

```
        a
START ----> ACCEPT
```